# How to insert values in column in MySQL where foreign key constraint points to primary key in the same table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have an error `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` whenever I am inserting new values to the table.

I have a foreign key which references another column(primary key) in the same table.

Comment: you must add a foreign key with 1 of previous rows

Comment: please show more of your data structure, your current data and the statement you use to insert the new data.

Comment: Added formatting to make the error message stand out from the text. Also please include some code with your problem, it makes it so much easier to understand.